# How to find the apparent power absorbed by a three phases load?

Tags: circuit-analysis, three-phase

Given a symmetric and balanced three-phases circuit, I would like to calculate the apparent power absorbed a three-phases delta load. I’m given the rms value of the line voltage applied to the load, which is 300V, and \$Z_\Delta = \sqrt{2}(1-j)\$. How can I find the apparent power absorbed by the three phases load?
I suppose the line voltage is equal to the phase voltage, so I calculate the power as \$P=\frac{V^2}{Z_\Delta}\$ and then I multiply it by 3, but I don’t think it’s right since the solution is \$135kVA\$

Comment: 300^2 / |sqrt(2)(1-j)| * 3 = 135 KVA !

Comment: It seems I'm having a little bit trouble getting to 135kVA. Where does the immaginary term go?

Comment: Magnitude of (1-j) is sqrt(2), then the denominator is 2. Does this make sense?

Comment: Yes, totally. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The current in each phase will be: $$I = \frac{V_{rms}}{Z_{\Delta}} = 150 \angle{45°}~ \text{A}\longrightarrow I_{rms} = 150~\text{A} $$

Apparent power is:
$$ P_{ap} = V_{rms} \cdot I_{rms} = 45~\text{kVA} $$

And the total apparent power is:
$$ P_{total, ap} = 3 \cdot P_{ap}=135~\text{kVA}$$

Comment: P_ap can (maybe should?) be designated by the letter S. Active power is P, apparent is S